# Add timespan to another timespan does not work

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

I have two timespans and I want to add the second timespan to the first timespan:

```
TimeSpan weeklyWorkTimeHours = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
TimeSpan? completeWorkTimeForCurrentDay = 
CalculateCompleteWorktime(currentWorkTimeItem).Value; /* I debugged through 
the code. This method returns a correct timespan with a correct value */
weeklyWorkTimeHours.Add(completeWorkTimeForCurrentDay.Value);
```

But even after the last line of code, weeklyWorkTimeHours contains 0,0,0.
Why doesn't add work in this context?

Comment: Show the definition of `CalculateCompleteWorktime` method and `currentWorkTimeItem` variable as well. And [`TimeSpan.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return new `TimeSpan` if you don't want ignore the return value.

Comment: Why add when you're adding to zero? Why not just take the second term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value is a new `TimeSpan`, the original `TimeSpan` is **not modified**.

Try this:

```
weeklyWorkTimeHours = weeklyWorkTimeHours.Add(completeWorkTimeForCurrentDay.Value);
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful for the OP

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I'm less confused about this.